# Same image saving to two separate fields?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, imageview

I have 2 image views (imageView & imageTwo) and four buttons (takePhoto and selectPhoto for each image view). Tapping each button displays the taken or selected photo in the corresponding image view. Great.

HOWEVER, I'm attempting to save the two photos taken to my database. For some reason, the first photo taken saves to my two different database fields (the same photo appears in both fields, instead of each different photo saving to the two separate fields). That said, the data seems to save correctly (see XML output).

Why is this? See code below (sorry for the lengthy post).

**viewcontroller.m**

```
 //PHOTO ONE UPLOAD TAKE AND SELECT

    - (IBAction)selectPhoto:(id)sender {
        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.allowsEditing = YES;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        selectedImageView = self.imageView; // Add this

        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }

    - (IBAction)takePhoto:(id)sender {
        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.allowsEditing = YES;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        selectedImageView = self.imageView; // Add this

        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }

    - (IBAction)takePhotoTwo:(id)sender {

        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.allowsEditing = YES;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        selectedImageView = self.imageTwo; // Add this

        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

    }

    - (IBAction)selectPhotoTwo:(id)sender {

        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.allowsEditing = YES;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        selectedImageView = self.imageTwo; // Add this

        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];


    }

    - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
        UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
        selectedImageView.image = image;

        [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    }


    - (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

        [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

    }


- (IBAction)saveButton:(id)sender {


    //FIRST IMAGE DATA

    NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.imageView.image, 0.5);

    NSMutableDictionary *file = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    NSString *base64Image = [imgData base64EncodedString];
    [file setObject:base64Image forKey:@"file"];
    NSString *timestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];
    NSString *imageTitle = _itemName.text;
    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@.jpg",@"public://stored/", imageTitle];
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg", imageTitle];
    [file setObject:filePath forKey:@"filepath"];
    [file setObject:fileName forKey:@"filename"];
    [file setObject:timestamp forKey:@"timestamp"];
    NSString *fileSize = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[imgData length]];
    [file setObject:fileSize forKey:@"filesize"];


    //SECOND IMAGE DATA

    NSData *secondimgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.imageTwo.image, 0.5);

    NSMutableDictionary *secondfile = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    NSString *secondbase64Image = [secondimgData base64EncodedString];
    [file setObject:secondbase64Image forKey:@"file"];
    NSString *secondtimestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];
    NSString *secondimageTitle = secondtimestamp;
    NSString *secondfilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@.jpg",@"public://stored/", secondimageTitle];
    NSString *secondfileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg", secondimageTitle];
    [secondfile setObject:secondfilePath forKey:@"filepath"];
    [secondfile setObject:secondfileName forKey:@"filename"];
    [secondfile setObject:secondtimestamp forKey:@"timestamp"];
    NSString *secondfileSize = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[secondimgData length]];
    [secondfile setObject:secondfileSize forKey:@"filesize"];



    [DIOSFile fileSave:file success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"File uploaded!");

        //FIRST IMAGE FILE

        [file setObject:[responseObject objectForKey:@"fid"] forKey:@"fid"];
        [file removeObjectForKey:@"file"];

        fid = [responseObject objectForKey:@"fid"];

        NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);


        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

        [dict setObject: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", fid] forKey:@"fid"];
        NSLog(@"%@", fid);

        NSDictionary *fidLangDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:dict] forKey:@"und"];

        [nodeData setObject:fidLangDict forKey:@"field_photo"];



    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Node did not save!");
    }];



    [DIOSFile fileSave:file success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"File uploaded!");

        //SECOND IMAGE FILE


        [secondfile setObject:[responseObject objectForKey:@"fid"] forKey:@"fid"];
        [secondfile removeObjectForKey:@"file"];

        fid = [responseObject objectForKey:@"fid"];

        NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);


        NSMutableDictionary *secondDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

        [secondDict setObject: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", fid] forKey:@"fid"];
        NSLog(@"%@", fid);

        NSDictionary *secondfidLangDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:secondDict] forKey:@"und"];

        [nodeData setObject:secondfidLangDict forKey:@"phototwo"];


        [DIOSNode nodeSave:nodeData success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            NSLog(@"Node saved!");
            UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPad" bundle:nil];
            ipadaccountViewController *AccountViewController = (ipadaccountViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyAccount"];
            [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:TRUE];



        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Node did not save!");
        }];



    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Node did not save!");
    }];
```

**XML Data upon save:**

```
<field_photo>
<und is_array="true">
<item>
<fid>265</fid>
<uid>5</uid>
<filename>phone.jpg</filename>
<uri>public://stored/phone_1.jpg</uri>
<filemime>image/jpeg</filemime>
<filesize>161858</filesize>
<status>1</status>
<timestamp>1460264800</timestamp>
<rdf_mapping/>
<alt/>
<title/>
<width>1536</width>
<height>1536</height>
</item>
</und>
</field_photo>

<phototwo>
<und is_array="true">
<item>
<fid>266</fid>
<uid>5</uid>
<filename>phone.jpg</filename>
<uri>public://stored/phone_2.jpg</uri>
<filemime>image/jpeg</filemime>
<filesize>161858</filesize>
<status>1</status>
<timestamp>1460264800</timestamp>
<rdf_mapping/>
<alt/>
<title/>
<width>1536</width>
<height>1536</height>
</item>
</und>
</phototwo>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in the second `[DIOSFile fileSave...` it should be `secondfile` instead of `file`.